# How to make visible another combo box on selection of a value in current combo box in java swing using netbeans 7

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox

How to make visible another combo box on selection of a value in current combo box in java swing using netbeans 7.Suppose if i have a label name country and then select a country (India) from the combo box1 and then i need another combo box (combo box2)appear the states that is assosiated with country(India) which i will retrive the values from my database.

Comment: Show us your attempts.With which part you have problems?

Comment: Instead of making the combo box appear out of thin air to the amazement of the user, why not disable it unless some value is chosen from the first combo box. That way the user has an idea of what to expect as far an data goes.

Answer (score 1):

try this example and replace your data:

```
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.ItemEvent;
import java.awt.event.ItemListener;

import javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        final String[] mainData = { "-Select-", "Sel 1", "Sel 2", "Sel 3" };
        final String[] subData1 = { "Sub Sel 11", "Sub Sel 12", "Sub Sel 13" };
        final String[] subData2 = { "Sub Sel 21", "Sub Sel 22", "Sub Sel 23" };
        final String[] subData3 = { "Sub Sel 31", "Sub Sel 32", "Sub Sel 33" };
        final DefaultComboBoxModel boxModel;
        final JComboBox box1, box2;
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Demo Frame/SuRu");
        Container contentPane = frame.getContentPane();
        box1 = new JComboBox(mainData);
        box2 = new JComboBox();
        contentPane.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        contentPane.add(box1);
        contentPane.add(box2);
        box2.setVisible(false);
        boxModel = new DefaultComboBoxModel();
        box2.setModel(boxModel);
        frame.setBounds(200, 200, 500, 200);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);

        box1.addItemListener(new ItemListener() {

            @Override
            public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent arg0) {
                box2.setVisible(true);
                boxModel.removeAllElements();
                if (box1.getSelectedIndex() == 0) {
                    box2.setVisible(false);
                } else if (box1.getSelectedIndex() == 1) {
                    for (String s : subData1) {
                        boxModel.addElement(s);
                    }
                } else if (box1.getSelectedIndex() == 2) {
                    for (String s : subData2) {
                        boxModel.addElement(s);
                    }
                } else if (box1.getSelectedIndex() == 3) {
                    for (String s : subData3) {
                        boxModel.addElement(s);
                    }
                }

            }
        });
    }
}
```